# Notepad++ or any other editor : move half of lines down

Tags: notepad++, editor

A great classic, more than likely - I want to go from this :

```
XXX, 1, A1
XXX, 2, A2
XXX, 3, A3
XXX, 4, A4
```

to this :

```
XXX, 1, A1
XXX, 2,
XXX, 3, A2
XXX, 4, A3
        A4
```

and then manually add the missing `XXX, 5,` on the last line (and filling in line 2 with a new element). Column edition proves useless here, unless there's something I'm missing.

Note : XXX is a fixed-length string.

Comment: What is `xxx`, is it a fixed-length string? Same question for `A1`, `A2` ... Are numbers `1, 2, 3` only 1 digit? Please, [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54197356/edit) and add real test cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The concept of column in Notepad++ is a single character width. This may be at odds with what might be considered a column in, for example, a comma seperated variable file.

The below method should work on the example, but that is strictly because the columns are fixed width.

- move the cursor to before `A2`
- while holding the Alt key, drag the selection down to the end of `A3` (using either the mouse or shift and arrow keys)
- cut the selection
- paste to the line below

Comment: This will only works if `xxx` is fixed length string.

Comment: yes, which in the example it is. The notion of column is based on character width, it is not based on any seperator.